# How to add objects in a List to a Vector?

Tags: java

I'm dealing with legacy code right here. I can't paste the code so I will give an example.

```
List list1 = <Objects returned from SQL SELECT results>
```

So basically list1 contains a number of objects. I've tested it was indeed there as I was using getters to confirm that there are objects in the list. Let's say there are a total of 3 objects.

I'm currently doing:

```
Vector vector1;

for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    vector1.add(list1.get(i));
}
```

But it does not work. How do I transfer objects from List to Vector?

Note that I cannot change the data type and it has to be List and Vector, I've tried adding casting to individual objects as well, and I have tested using `vector1.addElement()` as well, but neither works.

P:S: Java EE IDE Web Developer in Eclipse v4.6. My console doesn't write anything, and my front end just "pops" an error, that is why I'm confused as well. Apologies if I do not have enough information, just wanted to make sure that my method to transfer objects from List to Vector is correct.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? And what do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: "Doesn't work" in what way?  Error message at compile-time?  Exception thrown at runtime?  `Vector` just mysteriously ends up empty? Computer bursts into flames?  Details, please.

Comment: Java EE IDE Web Developer in Eclipse v4.6. My console doesn't write anything, and my front end just "pops" an error, that is why I'm confused as well. Apologies if I do not have enough information, just wanted to make sure that my method to transfer objects from List to Vector is correct.

Comment: Please open a console and enter `java -version`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Java version 1.8.0_221

Comment: It would really help to know what error you are getting, that will help

Comment: Well, your code should work. But you could also use `vector1.addAll(Iist1)`. However, doubt whether using `Vector` is the right choice here. In addition, you should not use raw types, that is, both `Vector` and `List` demand a *type argument*, and you should provide it. For example: `List<YourObjectType>` and `Vector<YourObjectType>`. Regarding your description of what happens – it looks like rather a build failure.

Comment: `vector1` is not initialized in your code snippet, so this should give you a compiler error

Answer (score 1):

Vector also implements `List` Interface, so you can try something like -

```
List vector1 = new Vector<>(list1);
```

For example -

```java
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
List vecor1 = new Vector(strings);
System.out.println(vecor1);
```

Comment: `new Vector(list1)` _does_ work, but not because `Vector` implements `List`.

Comment: Yeah because it has a constructor that takes in any Collection.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize vector1.

```
Vector vector1 = new Vector();
```

Answer (score 0):

As Vector is a list, you can use Collections#copy

```
Collections.copy(vector1, list1);
```